# Posting status update to IBM Connections Community

Tags: json, connection, opensocial, ibm-connections

I'm able to post a status update to an IBM Connections community. However the status update is visible in the Recent Updates section and not in the Status Update section.

I'm using the following URL:
https://host.com/connections/opensocial/rest/activitystreams/urn:lsid:lconn.ibm.com:communities.community:5a0fdd28-127e-4bd0-969f-ef1254ecd9dc/@all/@public

And the following JSON:

{"object":{"url":"url","objectType":"note","id":"109876b6-f33b-3210-45bc-966a5d2cc096-rai1sgp","displayName":"Tracy Morgan"},"title":"${add.target}","target":{"url":"https://host.com/communities/service/html/community/updates?communityUuid=5a0fdd28-127e-4bd0-969f-ef1254ecd9dc","objectType":"community","id":"urn:lsid:lconn.ibm.com:communities.community:5a0fdd28-127e-4bd0-969f-ef1254ecd9dc","displayName":"FEBER"},"verb":"post","generator":{"url":"url","id":"App","displayName":"inside.FEBER"},"actor":{"objectType":"person","id":"urn:lsid:lconn.ibm.com:profiles.person:8072DB8F-7FD2-497D-B341-8EA75B370C4D","displayName":"Vikram"}}

Is there something I need to change in the REST URL that will make the abpve JSON be populated in the Status Update section as well as the Recent Update section of IBM Connections. We are using IBM Connections 5.

Comment: P.S. I'm not getting a 401 or a 403. I'm getting a 200 response and the status update is posted. The issue is that its posted in the Recent Updates panel (left hand side) of the community and not in the Status Updates panel. Also I noticed that the status update disappears from Recent Updates after 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you are most likely running it an issue using the nonce.

Try this add the X-Update-Nonce header to your request.  You can get the Nonce value from the http://apps.na.collabserv.com/files/basic/api/nonce .

Add the Header to the HttpRequest 
It should then work.

http://bastide.org/2014/10/08/cross-site-request-forgery-and-ibm-connections-micro-blog/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not getting a 401 or a 403. I'm getting a 200 response and the status update is posted. The issue is that its posted in the Recent Updates panel (left hand side) of the community and not in the Status Updates panel. Also I noticed that the status update disappears from Recent Updates after 24 hours.

Comment: it'll be a 200 if you aren't getting the right authentication.  what's the body of the response?

Comment: {"entry":{"id":"urn:lsid:lconn.ibm.com:activitystreams.story:58a09747-e4b8-4fbf-a100-11bc009a1298"}}

Comment: then your post is succeeding.... you are just going to the wrong app - use https://host.com/connections/opensocial/rest/activitystreams/urn:lsid:lconn.ibm.com:communities.community:5a0fdd28-127e-4bd0-969f-ef1254ecd9dc/@all or https://host.com/connections/opensocial/rest/activitystreams/urn:lsid:lconn.ibm.com:communities.community:5a0fdd28-127e-4bd0-969f-ef1254ecd9dc/@all/@all